# Entity Framework Polymorphism

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, polymorphism

I wanted some help with trying to implement a simple polymorphic relationship using Entity Framework.

An example of a relationship I would like to implement:

> **Comment** table
>
> - ItemType ('Video', 'User')
> - ItemID
> - Body
>
> **Video** has many **Comments**
>
> **User** has many **Comments**

No idea the best way to do this,  I come from a Ruby on Rails way of thinking.

Comment: where is the polymorphism (ItemType?) ?

Comment: by polymorphism do you mean that Video and User share a base class that has Comments?

Comment: I believe he means that the relationship itself is polymorphic, it's Video -> Comment OR User -> Comment.  See for example http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/db-relationships/polymorphic 

So there are two separate FK relationships in the database but you want a single Interface. e.g.IHasComments and you can cast User or Video to IHasComments and then access the .Comments to get at them.

Inheritance is a separate issue - you can do this with or without an inheritance relationship between User and Video and some common parent type.

Answer (score 3):

This does not call for polymorphism (inheritance).

You state correctly: Video **has** Comments. Inheritance would require: Video **is a** Comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic choices are:-

**1. Inheritance**
Model `Videos` and `Users` as sub-classes of `Items` either:-

1.1. Table-per-class inheritance (so one table for Video, one for Users)

1.2 Table-per-hierarchy inheritance (so one table that contains video and users together (some fields hidden for some types)

I suggest you look up table-per-class and table-per-hierarchy for Entity Framework.

**2. Using generic interfaces (e.g. ICommentableObject<..>, ICommentableObjectContext<...>)**
This allows you to have separate Video, User, Comment tables and FKrelationships between then for VideoComment and UserComment (and more generally for any other tables you want to comment on).

This is do-able, but it's *very* complex.  For example, I have an ITaggable implementation which can apply tags to any ObjectContext and any objects within it that support the given interface - but it wasn't easy.

Comment: Eventhough it's been a long time since you answered this, but could you provide an example of how you created your ITaggable, or where lays the complexity?

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you should model DB like this:

Tables:

**Items** (ItemID, ItemType, Body)

**Users** (UserID, ...)

**Comments**(CommentID, ItemID, UserID)

Then you shouln't have any problems to have relationships between your entities.