# Polymorphic Relations in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have used Laravel in the past, and loved their [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) features.

> Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other
>   model on a single association. For example, imagine users of your
>   application can "comment" both posts and videos. Using polymorphic
>   relationships, you can use a single comments table for both of these
>   scenarios.

Is there something similar in Entity Framework Core? I'm using their Code First Approach.
Thanks

Comment: It's **not** supported in any EF version including Core.

Comment: I see, thanks for confirming. I will find another way around then.

Comment: did you found a way around it?

Comment: @wheeler Not really, I went back to the basic way, which is to have one model only belong to one other model.. e.g. if I have students and teachers, and both of them have addresses, I will make one student address table, and one teacher address table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Maybe it is too late but could still be helpful for someone with the same question.*

There sure is away of doing it and it is called TPH you can find more information on how to do it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance.

However it has 1 major drawback if you want to use 1 table for 2 entities (2 parent tables) then you cannot have a ForeginKey Constraint on the Comments table.

The way you can do the setup is by having 2 columns on the Comments table 1 called EntityType and LinkId. The column EntityType would be the Discriminator column and it will tell you to which parent table this comment belongs either to a post or a video. and the LinkId will tell to which record in the Video table the Comment belongs to

Hope this answers it.

Comment: How do you set this up then?

Comment: @puerile What you do is have a base class called Lets say Address which has common properties and it has a LinkType (Discriminator) and LinkId. Let me know if you still need more info

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and I found 3 possible solutions:

1. Implement some interfaces like `IComentableObject`.
2. Model Comments table like this:

   ```
   Comments(CommentID, ..., PostID, VideoID)
   ```
3. TPH pattern applies here?

[Older question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2607414).